# Where should I ask a question about Google Chrome?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

The question is very similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347182/how-to-make-backspace-work-in-google-chrome), but I don't think that that question should be on the Ubuntu site (doesn't seem to be Ubuntu specific).

To be specific my question is: "Since the change in Chrome 35.0 that makes backspace a shortcut for back on Linux, how do you disable this feature?"

Is there a site in the Stack Exchange network that would be appropriate for this question?

Comment: Super User probably fits the bill. Check their help center documentation before posting, to make sure it does indeed.

Comment: @Oded you're right, from the SU help center `Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about... computer software...`

Comment: **Not a duplicate** any more. [That broad question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/209317) never mentions Chrome. [That blunderbuss of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/209317) never mentions SuperUser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) ([`google-chrome`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome)) for sure, or perhaps [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) ([`chrome`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome)).

Answer (score 3):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/ will go I think. (because you pointed that you ask about linux) Or maybe http://superuser.com.